# "NavigateUrlField" attribute in Sharepoint TreeView Not working?

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Am doing a sample Project for my company in Sharpoint designer . While trying to create a treeview navigation for organization chart ,  am Getting the below error :

> **Could not bind to the 'url' property (specified by NavigateUrlField) while data binding TreeView.  Please check the Bindings fields.**

The odd thing is that I've tested by assigning a string to the NavigateUrl property directly, then putting the same string in the url field in the xml. Doing it manually works without a problem, but the same string won't work if it comes from the xml.

Any kind of advice is highly appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you use fully qualified URL or a path. You should set "Nav" property in node tage, and then set NavigateUrlField as "Nav".

Please refer this this will help you:

[TreeNodeBinding.NavigateUrlField Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodebinding.navigateurlfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)